# Mostrar sugestões enquanto digita autocomplete

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho o seguinte `autoComplete` :

```
<p:autoComplete id="geracao" value="#{habilidademb.habilidade.geracao}"
    completeMethod="#{habilidademb.listarGeracoes()}"
    dropdown="true" var="bean" itemLabel="#{bean.nome}" 
    itemValue="#{bean}" converter="#{geracaoConverter}" effect="bounce"/>
```

Quando estou digitando nele, ele abre todas as opções e vai marcando as que casam com o texto que estou digitando. Gostaria que ele só mostrasse as opções que casassem com meu texto. Como posso fazer isso? O meu `completeMethod` é:

```
public List<Geracao> listarGeracoes() throws Exception 
{    
    this.geracoes = gDao.findAll();
    return this.geracoes;
}
```

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

Comment: Já tinha olhado mas não compreendi como vou fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode tentar o seguinte:

```
public List<Geracao> listarGeracoes(String query) throws Exception
{
    /*
     * 1a. Opção: fazer um método no seu dao para buscar por nome diretamente no banco
     */
    //return gDao.buscarPorNome(query);

    /*
     * 2a. Opção: filtrar os resultados com base na query
     */
    List<Geracao> retorno = new ArrayList<Geracao>();
    for (Geracao g : gDao.findAll()) {
        String teste = g.getNome();
        if (teste.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())) {
            retorno.add(g);
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

E no seu autoComplete, modifique o `completeMethod="#{habilidademb.listarGeracoes}"` e adicione `minQueryLength="3"` para que faça a busca a partir de 3 caracteres.

Comment: E qual parâmetro eu passo quando for chamar o método ?

Comment: Desculpa, tem que modificar o completeMethod para: "#{habilidademb.listarGeracoes}"

Comment: Show, funcionou, porque tem que tirar o () do método ?

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Acho que o componente deve procurar por padrão um método com um parâmetro string implicitamente, semelhante aos listeners com parâmetros, que também não precisam do ().